# How can I break down one big arraylist into several arrraylists inside a hashmap?

Tags: java, hashmap

Example: One query throws the next result set:

Name | Age | Grand Total

- John Smith, 45, 1000
- John Smith, 56, 800
- John Smithers, 34, 500
- John Smyth, 56, 500
- John Smyth, 56, 1100

I want to separate this arraylist into three, and store them in a hashmap where the key is the client name.

I was thinking something like

```
Arraylist<Row> rows = dao.getClientActivity();
Map map = new HashMap<Clients Name, Clients Row>();
Arraylist<Row>  = null;


for (Row row : rows){

    if (map.get(row.clientName) == null) list = new ArrayList<Row>();

    list.add(row);

    if(map.get(row.clientName) == null) map.put(row.clientName, list);

}
```

The list will always be sorted by name.

Take the upper snippet as pseudo code, I don't have coding programs at home, I just got that off the top of my head, I think I tested something like that this friday but it only printed on row;

I don't know if there's a better way to do this, but this is the first thing I come up with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your map declaration should be as follows (assuming `Row.clientName` is `String`):

```
Map<String, List<Row>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Row>>();
```

And the for loop should look like as follows:

```
for (Row row : rows){
    /*Get the list of rows for current client name.*/
    List<Row> currRows = map.get(row.clientName); 
    if (currRows == null) {/*If not list exists for*/
        currRows = new ArrayList<Row>(); /*create a new one*/
        map.put(row.clientName, currRows); /*and put it in the map*/
    }
    currRows.add(row);/*add the current row to the list*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that there is no way that you can change the input format.

I would suggest that you create a model to represent a client:

```
public class Client {

    private final String name;
    private final byte age; //Nobody should be older than 256
    private final int total;

    /* Construct model */

    /* Getters/Functions */

}
```

I would also suggest that you create a factory method inside `Client` to create the class from your string input.

```
public static Client parseClient(String clientRep){

    String[] clientData = clientRep.split(',');

    Client newClient = new Client(); //TODO: Name conventionally. 

    newClient.name = clientData[0];
    newClient.age = Byte.valueOf(clientData[1]);
    newClient.total = Integer.valueOf(clientData[2]);

    return newClient;

}
```

Now, you can add these to a map (`Map<String, Client>`).

```
String clientFromWherever = getWhateverDataFromWherever();

Map<String, Client> clientel = new HashMap<>();

Client addingToMap = Client.parseClient(clientFromWherever);

clientel.put(addingToMap.getName() /* or however the name should be got */, addingToMap);
```

That should do well enough.

=====

However - if you should not want to use the client object, I would suggest creating a `Map<String, int[]>` and storing that age and charge in the array. If your charges do not exceed `Short.MAXVALUE` use a `short[]`. Storing a large number of arraylists (or any complex collections) just to store that little amount of data is unecessary.

```
ArrayList<Row> rows = dao.getClientActivity();
Map<String, int[]> clientelData = new HashMap<>();

for(Row clientRow : rows) {

    if (!map.containsKey(clientRow.clientName) {

        int[] clientNumericalData = new int[2];

        map.put(clientRow.clientName, clientNumericalData);

    }

}
```